# Rendered vs Lookdev problems with appending model

Tags: rendering

Newbie issues.  I downloaded a couple of free blender models of the earth and moon.  When I attempt to append the moon to the earth blender file, there is a big problem with the renders.  Would appreciate advice on how to correct the issue.  Thanks in advance!

Link to free moon model: https://free3d.com/3d-model/moon-photorealistic-2k-853071.html

Link to free earth model: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/900/

This is what it looks like in Blender 2.8 beta (recent)
[image]

Comment: If the moon is deformed by displacement, it's due to Lookdev being unable to render displacement on objects.

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question descriptive of the problem yo uare having, instead of just the general problem.